# Java - If-statement returns false

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I've got a button "addspieler" and when I first press it, the second if statement returns true and view.addbox is executed (I want to add an JComboBox every time the button is pressed). But after the execution the if-statement returns always "false" and view.addbox is not going to be executed anymore. I don't know why. Thanks for advice!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == view.button1) {
                view.zeige_AuswahlNeuesSpiel(modell.getSpieler());

            }

            if (e.getSource() == view.button_addSpieler) {
                view.add_Box(modell.spieler_Anzahl_NeuesSpiel, modell.getSpieler());

            }

    }
```

view.addbox =

```
 public void add_Box(int anz_spieler, ArrayList<Spieler> spieler_Liste)
        {
            if(ct >= anz_spieler)
                return;



            jcombo_Liste = erstelle_Box(anz_spieler);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
            setLayout(layout);


            jcombo_Liste.get(ct).addItem(spieler_Liste.toArray());






            button_addSpieler = new Button("Spieler hinzufügen");
            button_addSpieler.addActionListener(darts_controller);

            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            f1.add(button_addSpieler,gbc);


            gbc.gridx = ct;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            f1.add(jcombo_Liste.get(ct),gbc);

            ct = ct+1;
            f1.repaint();


        }
```

Comment: `if` statements don't "return" anything.

Comment: Are you *sure* the method is not called? Have you verified that using print statements or breakpoints? It could just be that the `if` in that methods returns `true` since the player number now reaches some constraint.

Comment: Most likely, it's happening because `ct >= anz_spieler` becomes `true` after the first click. If you know how to use a debugger, you can find and fix such types of problems quickly.

Comment: I think I found my mistake. By creating a new object button it compared the old button with the new one. UI programming is still new to me. Thanks anyway guys!